# Kernel + Mutliple SVM's + Platt Scaling = 1 layer neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, pca, svm, kernel-trick

I have built my own Support Vector Machine by using quadratic programming and I'm using Kernel PCA with SVM. The output is `tanh` e.g Platt scaling.

When I combinde all these technologies....I looked at my model and it looks exactly as a 1 layer neural network. It also behaves excatly as 1 layer neural network.

Can it be that if I combine multiple SVM with platt scaling ... I will get a 1 layer neural network, just by training the model with quadratic programming, instead of back propagation?